# FileNotFoundException when uploading document in liferay's document_library subfolder

Tags: java, liferay

I get the following error everytime I upload document in the document_library subfolder's folder in liferay in our server.

Say I have a public folder in the document_library and inside of it I have Promos subfolder and inside of it, it contains a folder named test. I've already looked on the folder's permission and also the user's permission if the user is permitted to add documents. And it is.

```
[#|2011-09-15T17:10:40.961+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=76;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8181-23;|17:10:40,959 ERROR [jsp:157] com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/tomcat5/glassfishv2/data/document_library/10123/3888602/13001/1.0 (No such file or directory)
    at com.liferay.documentlibrary.util.FileSystemHook.addFile(FileSystemHook.java:113)
    at com.liferay.documentlibrary.util.HookProxyImpl.addFile(HookProxyImpl.java:76)
    at com.liferay.documentlibrary.util.SafeFileNameHookWrapper.addFile(SafeFileNameHookWrapper.java:102)
    at com.liferay.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLLocalServiceImpl.addFile(DLLocalServiceImpl.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl.addFileEntry(DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl.java:226)
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl.addFileEntry(DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl.java:120)
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLFileEntryServiceImpl.addFileEntry(DLFileEntryServiceImpl.java:70)
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryServiceUtil.addFileEntry(DLFileEntryServiceUtil.java:61)
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.action.EditFileEntryAction.updateFileEntry(EditFileEntryAction.java:305)
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.action.EditFileEntryAction.processAction(EditFileEntryAction.java:81)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortletRequestProcessor.process(PortletRequestProcessor.java:170)
    at com.liferay.portlet.StrutsPortlet.processAction(StrutsPortlet.java:188)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:50)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:639)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:672)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.processAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:361)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processPortletRequest(LayoutAction.java:738)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:548)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:217)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/tomcat5/glassfishv2/data/document_library/10123/3888602/13001/1.0 (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:131)
    at com.liferay.portal.util.FileImpl.write(FileImpl.java:785)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.FileUtil.write(FileUtil.java:306)
    at com.liferay.documentlibrary.util.FileSystemHook.addFile(FileSystemHook.java:92)
    at com.liferay.documentlibrary.util.HookProxyImpl.addFile(HookProxyImpl.java:76)
    at com.liferay.documentlibrary.util.SafeFileNameHookWrapper.addFile(SafeFileNameHookWrapper.java:102)
    at com.liferay.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLLocalServiceImpl.addFile(DLLocalServiceImpl.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy329.addFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl.addFileEntry(DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl.java:226)
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl.addFileEntry(DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy320.addFileEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLFileEntryServiceImpl.addFileEntry(DLFileEntryServiceImpl.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy321.addFileEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryServiceUtil.addFileEntry(DLFileEntryServiceUtil.java:61)
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.action.EditFileEntryAction.updateFileEntry(EditFileEntryAction.java:305)
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.action.EditFileEntryAction.processAction(EditFileEntryAction.java:81)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortletRequestProcessor.process(PortletRequestProcessor.java:170)
    at com.liferay.portlet.StrutsPortlet.processAction(StrutsPortlet.java:188)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:50)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:639)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:672)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.processAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:361)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processPortletRequest(LayoutAction.java:738)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:548)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:217)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.|#]

[#|2011-09-15T17:10:40.962+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=76;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8181-23;|action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:152)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:625)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:602)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:333)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:294)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:139)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:382)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:134)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:333)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.etag.ETagFilter.processFilter(ETagFilter.java:47)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:242)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:128)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:213)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.cache.CacheFilter.processFilter(CacheFilter.java:442)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.ca|#]

[#|2011-09-15T17:10:40.963+0800|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=76;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8181-23;|talina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:254)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:382)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.I18nServlet.service(I18nServlet.java:101)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:333)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:181)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:243)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.bdo.clg.util.filter.ControlPanelAccessFilter.doFilter(ControlPanelAccessFilter.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.bdo.clg.util.filter.AuditLogFilter.doFilter(AuditLogFilter.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.threadlocal.ThreadLocalFilter.processFilter(ThreadLocalFilter.java:37)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:313)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:666)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:872)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLReadTask.process(SSLReadTask.java:444)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLReadTask.doTask(SSLReadTask.java:230)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:264)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:106)
```

Comment: Can you post (some of) the code that is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you're accessing the Liferay Document Library in your code, then you should be using the Liferay API namely the DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil and DLFolderLocalServiceUtil classes.

Are you doing this programmitcally or through the Document Library GUI in the control panel?